# How do I turn my Swing drawing program into an applet?

Tags: java, html, swing, applet

I have a fully working Java Swing, drawing application.  I would like create an applet using this program for some sweet sweet extra credit in my Internet based computing class, but I'm not really sure how to approach this.

Any tips or guides?  I've made some simple applets to print out string, or change the window background, but I'm not sure how to turn my program into an applet.

Thank for any help.

Comment: Generally, a Swing/frame program is almost the same as an applet.  Applets have greater restrictions, see [What Applets Can and Cannot Do](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html).  The user experience is probably also going to be different, as tend to not what to have a `JMenuBar`, as it looks strange for the window to have two menu bars, but that's just me.  How you would physically go about making the program into applet will depend on how you wrote the original

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) The best way to deploy a Java desktop application is using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).